# Jquery UI Datepicker return minDate

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker, uidatepicker

I'd like to think I'm tech savvy, but my experience with js is all code-hacking, so I really don't know what I'm doing.

I have all of the options of the datepicker set up in an external js file. The datepicker is for selecting a delivery date. In the header, I have a clock that counts down to 2 PM - the latest we can deliver. At 2, the clock turns off and is replaced with an image. However, we don't delivery on Sundays or specific dates set in the datepicker options, but the clock still shows on those dates.

I want the clock to read the next available delivery date from the dateicker (set by minDate). Is there any way for me to call that variable from my datepicker options back to the header?

Comment: Can you post your code for setting up the datepicker. What is in your "external js file".

Comment: It's long but I'll post a link to the whole file

Answer (score 0):

```
var minDate = $( "%your_selector%" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate" );
```

Comment: @Christian it will work on the page where you have datepicker allready initialized

Comment: Can I initialize it in the header without displaying it?

Comment: @Christian sure. you just need to initialize it on text field (to prevent embeding inline) and hide this text field.

Comment: I'll get back to you ASAP. I initialized the datepicker in the header, but the blocked off dates are not showing up correctly. I have to figure that out first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option getter for the datepicker:

```
$(selector).datepicker('option', 'minDate');
```

[jQuery UI Datepicker - minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)